# Django crispy forms does not render css

Tags: python, css, django, django-crispy-forms, django-bootstrap3

I am trying to use django crsipy forms to render a really really simple form. Fiddling around for hours now but don't get it rendered using bootstrap (or for the sake of it any css-template). As I am just starting to get a grasp of Django in general I might miss anything substantial. I do not get any errors.

Here is how i installed and setup the packages:

- Installed django-crispy-forms and django-bootstrap3 via pip.
- Both are listed under `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py
- `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK` is set to `'bootstrap3'`

If I understood it correctly - thanks to the django-bootstrap3 package - I do not have to add any static files to my app nor do I have to load them in the template.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models    
class Crispy_test(models.Model):
        pnumber = models.CharField("Projectnumber", max_length=5, unique = True)
        client = models.CharField("Client", max_length=20)
        pname = models.CharField("Projectname", max_length=40)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Crispy_test

class Crispy_testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Crispy_test
        fields = ['pnumber', 'client', 'pname', 'status']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import ProjectForm, Crispy_testForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Crispy_testForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('success')
    else:
        form = Crispy_testForm()

    return render(request, 'projectmanager/index.html', {'form': form})
```

and finally the related template index.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
```

Comment: On further investigation I also tried to render the `form.as_table`, `form.as_p` and `form.as_ul` without any additional css.
`form.as_p` and `form.as_ul` works as intended but `form.as_table` won't create the necessary html tags. Could these issues be related under any circumstances?